# How to find out which apps aren't shown on home screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, library, springboard

I have deleted a folder on my iPhone and removed the containing apps from homescreen. Now they are only in the App Library after the last homescreen.

I don’t know exactly what apps where in this folder.

How can I check which apps are only in the App Library and not on the homescreen?
Is there a Shortcuts that can create a list?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to script this in Shortcuts or find it in settings as a list with iOS 16.2

The best you can do is long press and hold on an app in the App Library and add it to the Home Screen.

[image: add to Home Screen image from iOS App Library]

Comment: In the past, I've seen a screen with two tabs: "All" and "Not on this iPad."  But I can't seem to find it now, not even on an older iPad that can't update to the latest O.S.

Comment: That is functionality in the App Store app and in some MDM reports I’ve seen @WGroleau

Comment: I looked in the App Store app and in the App store settings.